# Regex does not return all matches for same start char and multiple endings

Tags: regex

In this below regex:

```
1.*(aaa|ccc)
```

Test string

```
1aaaccc
```

There is only one match with Group 1 ccc. But there should be two matches aaa and ccc

Comment: `(|)` is an alternation, so you're matching *either* `aaa` or `ccc`. Since you've specified `1.*(aaa|ccc)`, it'll match `1aaaccc`, capturing `ccc` since regex *wants* to match as much as possible. Similarly, changing it to `1.*?(aaa|ccc)` (lazy matching) will only match `1aaa`. I think what you're looking for is maybe `1.*(a{3})(c{3})`

Comment: Can you add more examples to clarify your requirements better.

Comment: You can do that correctly with pure regex only in Perl6. You may use workarounds for this current scenario only in most regex flavors (see top comment), or solutions based on some code and regex. What is your regex flavor?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you are looking for;
Pattern "1.*(aaa|ccc)" will extract two groups:

1. "1aaaccc": '1' + any characters + 'ccc'. 'ccc' is picked as default 'greedy' matching: extract as much as possible.
2. "ccc" - because "ccc" is in 'capturing group'. You can suppress that, changing pattern to "1.*(?:aaa|ccc)". It is "ccc" and not "aaa" because it represents part of already existing match. All optional matches after the first one are fragments of the first one.

If you remove ".*", then "ccc" will became irrelevant and you will have "1aaa" and "aaa".
If you want to get both "aaa" and "ccc", the pattern must be "1(aaa)(ccc)". Result will be: "1aaaccc", "aaa", "ccc". But it may be not what you need: the string "1xxxccc" will not match anything.

It is for .NET regex, other flavors most probably will give the same result.
Hope my description makes sense :)

Comment: `the first one` is the entire match, it's not formally a capture group. Really known as _`the match`._